# Finding the number of years (age) between 2 date variables in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have two variables:

The first variable is BIRTH_DATE in Day, Month, Year format. Ex. 31-Oct-76

The second is EVENT_DATE in Day, Month, Year as well. Ex. 25-Aug-04

I want to create a new variable called "Age" that is calculated as the number of years between these two dates. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
df$diff_years <- 

as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(df$EVENT_DATE, format="%d-%b-%y")
                    , as.Date(df$BIRTH_DATE, format="%d-%b-%y")
                    ,unit="weeks"
                    )
           ) / 52.25
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this for all observations under the BIRTH_DATE and EVENT_DATE variables or do i need to input  each date individually?

Comment: Hi, @JohnTayson course not. Answer updated :)
I assumed your dataframe is called `df`. Updated as needed

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the full year value

```
BIRTH_DATE <- as.Date("31-Oct-76", format="%d-%b-%y")
EVENT_DATE <- as.Date("25-Aug-04", format="%d-%b-%y")

Age <- length(seq.Date(from=BIRTH_DATE, to=EVENT_DATE, by="year"))-1
Age
[1] 27
```

Use `apply` to use it on a data frame

```
df$Age <- apply(df, 1, function(x) 
  length(seq.Date(from=as.Date(x["BIRTH_DATE"], format="%d-%b-%y"),
                    to=as.Date(x["EVENT_DATE"], format="%d-%b-%y"), by="year"))-1)
df
  BIRTH_DATE EVENT_DATE Age
1  31-Oct-76  25-Aug-04  27
2  31-Oct-76  25-Aug-04  27
3  31-Oct-76  25-Aug-04  27
4  31-Oct-76  25-Aug-04  27
5  31-Oct-76  25-Aug-04  27
```

Comment: @JohnTayson `class(BIRTH_DATE)` and `class(EVENT_DATE)` should be `Date`. If not somethings went wrong in assigning the dates. In any case, when I copy the lines it works fine.

Comment: @JohnTayson Ah, you mean on a data frame. I added an approach with `apply`.

Comment: This is my current code:

`humanyr <- transform( humanyr,
                      bday = as.Date(humanyr$BIRTH_DATE, format="%d-%b-%y"),
                      eday = as.Date(humanyr$EVENT_DATE, format="%d-%b-%y"),
                      Age <- length(seq.Date(from=bday, to=eday, by="year"))-1
)`

Do you know why `BIRTH_DATE <- as.Date("31-Oct-76", format="%d-%b-%y")` would be converting 30-May-67 into 2067 instead of 1967?

Comment: @JohnTayson because dates are counting from 1970 in R. That's their origin.

Comment: @JohnTayson You can have dates before that, but then you have to define them explicitly with `1967` and `%Y` (upper case Y).

Answer (score 0):

Please see this example which may be short and elegant:

```
library(lubridate)

#generate example data
df=data.frame(BIRTH_DATE= rep(dmy("31-Oct-76"),5),
EVENT_DATE=rep(dmy("25-Aug-04"),5))

#number of year
df$year=interval(df$BIRTH_DATE, df$EVENT_DATE) / years(1)

df
#  BIRTH_DATE EVENT_DATE     year
#1 1976-10-31 2004-08-25 27.81694
#2 1976-10-31 2004-08-25 27.81694
#3 1976-10-31 2004-08-25 27.81694
#4 1976-10-31 2004-08-25 27.81694
#5 1976-10-31 2004-08-25 27.81694
```